# Inserting an image to a SQL Server 2008 table using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to insert a new product into the `product` table, one of the columns is an image. This is my code:

```
 private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Title = "Open Image";
        dlg.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName);
            ImageToByte(pictureBox1.Image);
        }

        dlg.Dispose();
    }

    public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
    {
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
    }
```

I'm getting this error :

> Failed to convert parameter value from a Bitmap to a Byte[].

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Save your image to a memory stream, then convert to an array of byte :

```
private byte[] ImageToByte(System.Drawing.Image imageToConvert,
                                                   System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat formatOfImage)
            {
                byte[] Ret;
                try
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        imageToConvert.Save(ms, formatOfImage);
                        Ret = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception) { throw; }
                return Ret;
            }
```

Sample Usage for a Bitmap in your case

```
ImageToByte( [your image here], System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(this Image image, ImageFormat format)
{
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(ms, format);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

and use this:

```
var image = yourImageFromPictureBox;
byte[] arr = image.ToByteArray(ImageFormat.Bmp);
```